# How do I send private messages?

Tags: discussion

There are some really bright, talented people here that I would love to know whether they have a PhD, teach etc.

Is there any way to send someone a private message here?

Comment: FYI: [Users opt-in to be always pingable to answer questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/1159/2451).

Answer (score 14):

There is [no](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/4830/2509) private [messaging](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/57203/2509) system, [nor will there ever be](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/85255/2509). The team has been [quite firm](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/431/2509) on this. The mantra is

> This is not a social network.

[Options that are available to you](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57537/how-do-i-contact-other-users):

- @-tagging the user in a comment (which you should probably delete afterwards)
- @-tagging the user in chat
- Looking in the user's profile: people who want to be contacted out-of-band can provide the means there.

Comment: For what it's worth, @-tagging in chat only works if the user has posted in the room in the past 2 days, as far as I know.

Comment: It would be useful if people could at least post comments on people's profile page if the option was enabled by the user. At least a thanks every now and again would be appreciated by some, possibly, as done at physicsforums which hasn't degenerated into a social network.

Comment: what do you mean by point #1? if you are commenting on someone's post they are always notified no matter what you type in the comment .. see the "help" link under the "add comment" button, etc

Comment: @Jeff: whom did you [intend](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104691/no-notification-of-a-comment-on-an-answer-to-my-question/104694#104694) to @ notify here?

Comment: @tobias all comments are addressed to the post owner unless they explicitly state otherwise.

Comment: @jeff ah sorry, I misread your comment as intended to reply to user2146, never mind... I think dmckee meant the (not so reliable?) fact that a notification remains in the inbox even if the original comment has already been deleted. But since the inbox abbreviates, that's not that good a solution. Then again, someone not mentioning means for private contact will probably ignore that anyway

Comment: @tobias deleted comments are always deleted, there is a special case for *moderator comments* on a *post which is then deleted* but .. it's very special purpose